# How to bind a (Clojure) Aleph TCP server to a TCP v4 port?

Tags: tcp, clojure, netty

I started to learn Clojure a couple of days ago. I was trying with some Aleph TCP echo server examples but I can not get the server to bind to a tcp v4 port. The server only binds to a tcp v6 port by default.

Here my project file:

```
(defproject clj-echo-server "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Echo server with Aleph"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
  :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [aleph "0.3.0-beta12"]]
  :main clj-echo-server.core)
```

And the server code:

```
(ns clj-echo-server.core)

(use 'lamina.core 'aleph.tcp 'gloss.core)

(defn handler [ch client-info]
  (receive-all ch
    #(enqueue ch (str "You said " %))))

(start-tcp-server
  handler
  {:port 9000, :frame (string :utf-8 :delimiters ["\r\n"])})
```

I can figure out if I'm doing something wrong or how to configure the binding port, the documentation wasn't very helpful about tcp ports.

My OS is an Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, the Leiningen version is 2.0.0-preview10 and all runs on Java 1.6.0_24 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM.

Can anyone advise me on how to configure the port binding for the tcp server?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, but I've added in support for a `:host` keyword in the latest Aleph snapshot in `0.3.0-SNAPSHOT`.  This should have already been in there, thanks for catching my oversight.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably binding to your localhost interface rather than whatever outward-facing network card you want it to use. I don't know about aleph's tcp server specifically, but most servers let you specify the interface to listen on as an IP address: if given a v4 address, then it would do what you want. For aleph, maybe that's `:host` or `:interface`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @amalloy. I tried with your suggestions but the problem still persist. Apparently just ignore those values.